# Replace div content from one page with div content from another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a page with links in a nav. When a user clicks Page B, I'd like to load content from Page B into the div #main-text of Page A but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm very new to js, so be easy on me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#nav_a").on("click", function(){
        $("#main_text").load("pageA.html");  
    });
    $("#nav_b").on("click", function(){
        $("#main_text").load("pageB.html");  
    });    
});
</head>
</script>

<body>
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="nav_a" href="#">Page A</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav_b" href="#">Page B</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="main_text">Page A</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Store the contents of one page in the client side (look into `localStorage`, `sessionStorage` or `cookies`) and use it to replace the contents in the second page.

Comment: Check for `console errors` on first instance.. In fact you dont need to `load` here through `ajax`.. You can just bring up all the stuffs and hide and show required stuff on click.,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pages are from the same domain as the page with the script and contain valid (x)html, then it should work.

**Note:** Ajax does NOT work from file system. It needs all files to come from a web server.

I would personally do

```
$(".nav a").on("click", function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault(); // cancel the click
  $("#main_text").load("page"+this.id.split("_")[1].toUpperCase()+".html"); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try your way. I'm just building this in a folder on my desktop. Would that matter?

Comment: Yes, it will not work. You need a web server or change the load to use the file API

Comment: Oh dear. Not sure how to do that. I'll have to hit the books. I appreciate the help.

Comment: The simplest is to upload the files to a server or install a simple http server